# Using Solr Admin Site

Tags: solr

I have given the following result if I using the search query field to find "hallo"

```
 "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "_ts": 5981360301826638000,
        "name": "hallo",
        "ns": "test.test",
        "_id": "530207ea395d4616f8038174",
        "REC.static_data.summary.names.name.full_name": "Pritchett, C. Herman",
        "_version_": 1460293044544733200
      }
    ]
  }
```

I also add the field `<field name="REC.static_data.summary.names.name.full_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />` and `<copyField source="REC.static_data.summary.names.name.full_name" dest="text"/>` in the schema.xml, but if I try to find Pritchett, C. Herman I get no result. Do I have to masquerade the comma and the dot?

[image: solr]

Comment: what it says if you append &debugQuery=true to the solr query?

Comment: What's your query? `REC.static_data.summary.names.name.full_name=Pritchett, C. Herman` ?

Comment: just Pritchett, C. Herman instead of hallo. Sorry now its working. I will try to reproduce this behavior. Maybe there is some issue in the process, if Iam indexing the data.

Comment: Now I have the same problem I add field to the schema.xml REC.UID, restart solr and start indexing my data. But I cant query the field REC.UID. But I can still query `REC.static_data.summary.names.name.full_name`.

Comment: Please check if you have indexed the REC.UID field as string.

Comment: Yes I add the following two lines to the schema.xml `<field name="REC.UID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />` and ` <copyField source="REC.UID" dest="text"/>`